# Verizon iPhone Provisioning Problems

Tags: iphone, sdk

I upgraded to XCode 4 and a Verizon iPhone 4.  After installing I am unable to sign and run anything on device.  Yes I HAVE added it to the portal (using organizer and on the website).  I've downloaded the certificates, and everything checks out.

I get the message:  XCode cannot run using the selected device.  No provisioned iOS devices are available. Connect an iOS device or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

Could this be due to the Verizon iphone being 4.2.8 and not 4.3?

EDIT: Also, my ipad runs fine on it.  Both devices show up in organizer, have the team provisioning certificates, and show up in the portal, etc...

-d

Comment: Solution: When I would plug in my phone it wouldn't be recognized by XCode. I clicked on the project name, then under the properties on the right pane I set the Devices to universaland set the deployment target to 4.2.  It ran just fine.  I then switched it back to iPhone and it ran fine. I also noticed it was now finding the correct iOS device name on the sim/device selector next to the play button. 

Not sure why this was happening.  I hope anyone having this issue find this post. If you need more elaboration on what I did just comment and I'll see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the iPhone is from Verizon has absolutely nothing to do with provisioning.

Try removing all of the certificates that are installed on the device currently, and try again. If the device is included in the certificates, then you should be good to go. Also ensure that you are running a supported iOS version on the device as set in your Xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

The foremost thing you'll want to do is make sure your app's deployment target isn't iOS 4.3 and is instead something lower. (Base SDK should remain as Latest iOS.)